# Print shape of tensor even when it is `None`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am creating a custom algorithm with a custom dataloader in Keras. I understand that when trying to access tensors inside the internal methods of the models that you often get a `None` when you print the shape of the tensor, often on the batch axis, as the batch size can be variable. I have created a custom method of updating gradients, and just for a sanity check I am trying to print the actual value of the the shape of this axis when the program is executing. I cannot figure out how to do it.

Here is some code, see where I wrote `THIS LINE`. This code will print out the following output, which shows the batch axis as `NONE`. Just for debugging purposes I would actually like to see what this value is when the code runs, how do I do that?

> (None, 4, 100)
> (None, 100) (None, 100, 100) (None, 100) (None, 100, 100) (None, 100)
> (None, 100, 1) (None, 1)

```
class CustomModel(keras.Model):
    def train_step(self, data):
        # Unpack the data. Its structure depends on your model and
        # on what you pass to `fit()`.
        x, y = data
        
        tao = 1

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y_pred = self(x, training=True)  # Forward pass
            # Compute the loss value
            # (the loss function is configured in `compile()`)
            loss = self.compiled_loss(y, y_pred, regularization_losses=self.losses)
            
        gradients = tape.jacobian(loss, self.trainable_variables)
        
        new_gradients = []
        for grad in gradients:

            print(grad.shape) # <--- THIS LINE

            q1 = K.mean( grad[:env_siz], axis=0 )
            q2 = K.mean( grad[env_siz:], axis=0 )

            Q = K.mean( K.stack((K.sign(q1), K.sign(q2))), axis=0 ) # 1 means all gradients in same direction on that axis
            P = tf.where( tf.abs(Q) >= tao, K.mean( K.stack((q1, q2)), axis=0 ), 0)
#             print(P)
            new_gradients.append( P )

        # Compute gradients
        trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
#         gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)
        # Update weights
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(new_gradients, trainable_vars))
        # Update metrics (includes the metric that tracks the loss)
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred)
        # Return a dict mapping metric names to current value
        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`tf.print`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/print) instead of `print` to be able to see values of tensors within "graphed" functions. Instead of accessing the `.shape` attribute, which will always be the statically-known shape, use [`tf.shape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape) to read the actual tensor shape.

```py
tf.print(tf.shape(grad))
```

Comment: That was it, I tried printing tf.shape but I didn't know about tf.print, thank you!